# SGS3: I have all LED indicators turned off, still get blue led when gmail sees an email and screen is off

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, notification-led

If I have LED Indicator/missed event set to off I wouldn't expect to see the blue led flashing.

I want the incoming email noise and icon as usual, just don't want it flashing away (I'm trying to sleep!). Don't want to have to turn phone face down.

Anyone know why it seems to ignore my settings?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not actually possible to fully disable the LED for Gmail without disabling email notifications altogether. Your only alternative is to use an app like LightFlow (of which there is a free, 'lite' edition).

Hopefully there will be a fix for this in a future update.

Comment: Hope so, this is a pretty big oversight. Why have settings when they don't get obeyed?